# Two like me can fit into this

Tags: word-usage

A got B a dress. But it was too big. So B jokingly says:

> You know what, two like me can fit into this.

Is the use of "two like me" natural?

Answer (score 1):

As a British English speaker, I would understand what you meant if you said this to me, but I would expect it far more likely that a native speaker would say, "You know what, two **of** me **could** fit into this."

Comment: I am not an expert on the English language and have no formal qualifications in English. I offer my advice only as a native British English speaker. I believe the advice of an untrained English speaker can sometimes be beneficial.

Comment: "two of me" is just English, nothing marked as British at all. two like me is sub-standard.